# How do I get the standard ANOVA table which has SSR, SSE, SSTO in Python?

Tags: python, statsmodels, anova, scipy.stats, minitab

I am trying to get an extra/sequence SS output with the following code:

```
reg2 = smf.ols(formula='Y ~ X3 + X2', data = df).fit()
anova_results2 = sm.stats.anova_lm(reg2, typ=1)
(anova_results2)
```

[image: This is the output in Python]

I would like it to look like the standard ANOVA output as shown below (obtained from Minitab). Is there any way to do it?

[image: Minitab output for extra/sequence SS]

Comment: Have you managed to figure it out?

Comment: I did not figure it out. As an alternative I used Minitab which gave a cleaner output than Python and had the standard rows and columns of an ANOVA table.